# maximum distance omnidirectional antenna

Tags: antenna, wire-antenna, wifi, loop-antenna

I want to know this omnidirectional antenna's maximum distance:

- gain 15 dBi
- frequency 2400 GHz
- power 50 watts

Answer (score 3):

**Antennas don't have ranges.** The maximum range of a link is determined by many factors in addition to the information you have about the antenna, among them:

- the power output of the transmitter (not the power rating of the antenna)
- the minimum usable signal of the *receiver*
- the strength of interfering signals
- the amount and type of obstacles (e.g. trees, building walls) between the two antennas

The only information you need about the antenna is its gain *in the relevant direction* (an “omnidirectional” antenna necessarily has less gain than a directional one).

Once you have gathered enough information, you can do a *link budget* calculation to model the expected performance. Have a look at the answers to this question: [What is a link budget, and how do I make one?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-a-link-budget-and-how-do-i-make-one)