# How far does a watt equal in range in the FM band?

Tags: antenna, fm, transmitter, range

How many watts would be needed to cover a 10 mile radius with good sound for music on the 88-108 MHz FM broadcast band? 
I am an amateur and for fun only.

Comment: Do you mean the 88-108 MHz FM broadcast band? The transmission of music is prohibited on any amateur band. Legal issues aside, the antenna will make a lot of difference with a given power.

Comment: @MikeWaters I will be an amateur at this and will remix all the music as a non profit  radio station.

Comment: Since this is now neither about *general radio theory* nor about *amateur radio*, it's become off-topic.

Comment: This is off-topic for sure, but you would need a LPFM license and plenty of power, with the antenna at a reasonable height.  Everyone always wants to minimize the amount of money but what you are proposing is commercial-level, and that will not be inexpensive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Non-profit radio is not amateur radio? "amateur ˈamətə,ˈamətʃə,ˈamətʃʊə,ˌaməˈtəː/ noun 1. a person who engages in a pursuit, especially a sport, on an unpaid basis. "it takes five years for a top amateur to become a real Tour de France rider" synonyms: non-professional." Please let this question stand, I am interested in the answers.

Comment: @user400344 no, it isn't. Please don't try to argue about the meaning of "amateur radio" on the ham stack exchange. Not every non-profit radio is amateur radio. That's not how language works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No need to block the question, he is interested in propagation per watt with various antennas and all that this entails. I am interested in the data, not quoting a thesaurus to a moderator.

Comment: @user400344 I'd love to agree with you, but this is a bad question on so many levels that being off-topic due to being explicitly against the definition of on-topicness for this site is the least one; it's underdefined, it asks for a product recommendation ("how much money do I have to spend?"), it shows no research effort and can't be answered without OP defining what "good sound" actually is. So yes, there is a need to vote for question closing, since that is how community based quality assurance works on StackExchange.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I concede. Is it impossible to message OP via SE? I have a few pointers for him that are only pollution of public thread.

Comment: I do not want to go commercial but more public in this endeavor. We are allowed to pay ourselves a salary under a non-profit status.

Comment: @Muze commercial interest is totally irrelevant to the problem at hand – you're asking about non-amateur operation (namely, music) in a non-amateur band.

Comment: @Mike Waters: In my country, transmission of music on some amateur band but only for test transmissions is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends in your intended communication. Are you trying to hit a fixed receiver, in which case you can aim an antenna to that receiver? or are you trying to communicate with a handheld or other portable system? Are you on a portable system? Is the target system on a hill? The gain on the receive antenna, as well as the radiation pattern of your antenna makes a huge difference.

Additionally, the actual band used may make a difference. Many different bands permit FM operation, and some have unique properties that increase propagation distance.

Often, a 5w handheld with a rubber duck can hit a repeater ~10-20 miles away, but this is one particular example of possible communication.

#### Edit:

As you mentioned that you want good quality for music, you'll really need a more powerful transmitter. Unfortunately, FCC part 97 (Amateur) rules [disallow music](https://nonbovine-ruminations.blogspot.com/2010/01/more-things-you-can-do-on-amateur-radio.html) through the amateur radio bands, so you'll likely need a commercial FM broadcast license to do that sort of thing.

I'm not qualified to talk at length about the particulars of antenna design, but there are other resources online. For broadcast FM radio, you'll need an antenna (a) in a high location, so receivers can clearly receive your signal; (b) high power, usually on the order of kilowatts. (WCBN-FM, a student radio station in Ann Arbor MI, uses a 200W transmitter, but has an effective range of around 10 miles).

Comment: Notice he said "good sound for **music**".

Comment: @MikeWaters The music bit was added after my answer was made.

Comment: Not 100% on-topic, but in the EU a lot of FM signals are moved to DAB+. That leaves a lot of good FM radios as garbage. Would like to keep mine in use.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [link budget](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/352/218) question. Transmit power is just one factor: others are terrain, antennas, frequency, quality, noise, and so on.

If we restrict the variables to typical values for FM commercial broadcast stations, we can use the [FCC's rules](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/fm-station-classes) to make some estimations. By that reckoning, you need a transmitter of around 50kW with an antenna 150 meters high to achieve your goal of high-quality coverage over a 20 mile radius.

Unfortunately, that's a very expensive transmitter. And you need a commercial license.